# Not every submodule has a complement submodule

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, modules

Precisely, suppose $S$ is a submodule of the $R$-module $M$, then it is not necessarily possible to decompose $M$ as

$$ M = S \oplus  S^c . $$

Any example?

It seems that there are many differences between vector spaces and modules. But I still cannot see the reason behind.

Comment: I assume $S^c$ is *not* the set complement of $S$, which is *never* a submodule. As an example, consider the $\Bbb  Z$-module $\Bbb Z_4$ and the submodule $\Bbb Z_2$. This doesn't have a complement.

Comment: Good example. But how to prove it?

Comment: @kaiser Note that the existence of such a compliment would imply an isomorphism of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules $\mathbb{Z}_4\cong\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$. Can you see why this can't happen?

Comment: @DavidHill Complement.

Answer (score 4):

Finding a direct-sum complement can fail in at least two ways:

- $S$ could be an *essential submodule* (this means that for another submodule $T$, $S\cap T=\{0\}$ implies $T=\{0\}$)
- $S$ could be a *superfluous submodule* (this means that for another submodule $T$, $S+T=M$ implies $T=M$.)

A good place to look for counterexamples is in rings which only have trivial idempotents, since idempotents correspond to module decompositions of the ring as a module over itself.

If you consider $\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$ as a module over itself, this module has exactly three submodules arranged in a line. The ring has no nontrivial idempotents. It's easy to see that the nontrivial submodule $2\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$ is both essential and superfluous at the same time, and so it (doubly) can't have a direct-summand complement.

[Semisimple rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semisimple_module#Semisimple_rings) are exactly the class of rings for which you can always find direct-summand complements.

> It seems that there are many differences between vector spaces and modules.

Of course. You might be interested in this question: [Pathologies in module theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/201603/29335)