# Big list of undergraduate exercises in module theory

Tags: reference-request, modules, big-list

I would like to write down a **big list of exercises in module theory addressed to a course of introduction to this subject**. The background of the average student will be the definition of ring, and some basic feeling with fields, PIDs, UFDs, domains in general and linear algebra.

I am looking for both *moral-exercises* (an example in linear algebra would be "is it true that given $v_1,v_2,v_3$ such that any pair is linearly independent, then they are linearly independent?) and *puzzle-exercises* (an example would in linear algebra would be "prove that any endomorphism of $\mathbb{R}^3$ has an invariant hyperplane").

The line of the course is far from computational algebra and is closer to a survey on abelian categories (without saying abelian category).

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201603/pathologies-in-module-theory) is a good starting point.

Comment: one of my favorite books is Hungerford's Algebra, great chapter on modules and lots of exercises.

Answer (score 4):

- Let $R$ be a unitary ring. If there are two different left inverses to an element $x\in R$ then there is an infinite number of left inverses for $x$. (extremely instructive, zero technology; a smart student with only the definition of ring can do it)
- the center of a simple ring is a field (one liner if you have the right idea)
- Let $M$ be an $R$-module and let $f, g \in End(M)$ such that if $f = fgf$ then $M\cong \ker f \oplus M'$ and $M\cong \text{im }f\oplus M''$, i.e. $\ker f$ and $\text{im } f$ are direct summands of $M$ (Bonus: Prove that the converse is also true.)
- If $M$ is either artinian or noetherian, then it [has the IBN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_basis_number).
- Is there a simple ring which is neither right noetherian, right artinian, left noetherian nor left artinian?
- Let $P_R$ be a right $R$-module. Define the *trace* $\textbf{tr} (M)$ of $P$ in a module $M_R$ to be the sum
  $$
  \textbf{tr} (M) = \sum_{f : P \to M} \text{im } f
  $$
  Prove that:

  1. $\textbf{tr} (M) = \text{im }\varphi$ for some $R$-module morphism $\varphi : P^{(I)} \to M$    ;
  2. $M\mapsto \textbf{tr} (M)$ is a functor.
- If I were you I'd package the whole injective-flat-projective story into some hidden definitions on orthogonality and exercises thereof.
- Same story for the tensor product stuff, we're in 2017: first a universal property and then you build a concrete object; and you use the universal property to do all the classical exercises.

Comment: Please, put many others!

Comment: For the most defiant exercise I can think of, a comment is enough: there is a bicategory whose objects are rings, 1-cells bimodules, and 2-cells module homomorphisms. Deduce the more you can about $Mod(R)$ using only this characterization.

Answer (score 0):

- A surjective endomorphism $M \to M$ of finitely generated module is in fact injective.

Comment: You should be sure to mention $R$ must be commutative ([this is the result I think you're thinking of](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/145362/29335)) otherwise this is false.  There are, in fact, rings with cyclic modules with surjections that aren't injective.